# How do you call Coherence (Elixir) from a test?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

My Elixir App is using Coherence for authentication. I am trying to write unit and functional tests for my app, but I don't know how to call the `login` function from the tests. Searching yielded very little examples on it's usage. Can someone who have done it before shed some light or examples how to do it ?

Comment: Maybe you should share some samples of what you've tried? The question you're asking sounds really simple and so I wonder if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

The `foo` function, that is declared in module `Bar` is called from everywhere as `Bar.foo`. So, to call `login` function, one should write the `Module.Where.Function.Belongs.To.login(params)`.

The `Coherence` project itself provides a [`Demo`](https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence_demo) pet project, that is in fact the great *how to* on `Coherence` usage. It also [contains tests](https://github.com/smpallen99/coherence_demo/tree/master/test) that are a very good starting point to write your own tests.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to set `current_user` in the `conn.assigns` for your test. If `conn.assigns[:current_user]` is set, the auth plugin will not attempt to authenticate the request.